# Pandas: Merging Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, and I want to merge them on a common column.

The first dataframe is a single column dataframe called dfLenders. the column name is `lender_ids`.

The second dataframe, called dfLoanLender, has two columns. One is "id" (the id of the loan) and another called "lender_ids" that contains a list of lenders who made that loan.

Notice that "lender_ids" is a column name in both tables. In the lender table, it is their id and appears once per row. In the loanLender table it represents a list of all lenders who made the loan. These are the same lender ids which are in the first table.

I use the following method from pandas:

```
dfMerged = pd.merge(dfLenders, dfLoanLender, on='lender_ids', how='outer')
```

using an outer join to provide the most generous room for error.

What I get is this following error:

```
"TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not map"
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
dfMerged = dfLenders.merge(dfLoanLender, right_on='lender_ids', left_index=True, how='outer')
```

I am suspecting that you might need to specify that you are wanting to merge on the index for the left DF.

I hope that helps!